# получение прямой ссылки на видео youtube

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

нужно на фон сайта вставить видео из `youtube`, в документации `youtube api` по ключевым фразам ничего не нашёл(с английским туго, не могу нормально юзать документацию). я делаю `ajax` запрос на свой сервер, он в свою очередь выполняет такой код(видео для примера):

```
$a = file("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=5q275vq5TZU");
echo urldecode($a[0]);
```

в консоли браузера это выглядит как строка в несколько тысяч символов длинной, причём консоль показывает эту строку всегда по разному(не знаю глюк ли это из за размера или строки действительно разные), на клиенте делаю `decodeURIComponent(html).split("url=")` , и получаю ~20 элементов(всегда по разному), и вручную можно вычленить ссылку на видео, если убрать весь мусор(всякие параметры), но сделать это автоматически я не могу(всегда разный мусор).

я вообще правильный метод использую? как получить ссылку с `YouTube` которую я потом вставлю в `html5 video`?

Comment: У вас разные вопросы в названии и описании. Что вам нужно, определитесь?)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMdHDHEuOUE
```

Замените CMdHDHEuOUE  на ваш videoId

Comment: и что с этим дальше делать?

Comment: <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

Comment: этот фрейм загрузит ещё и проигрыватель, это лишнее

Comment: @PashaPash, посмотрите внимательно на вопрос. Вопрошающий просит способ получения ссылки не для фрейма, а для html5 video. Это совершенно разные ссылки.

Comment: @Visman "не является ответом" стоит использовать только для комментариев, правок, других вопросов, запощенных как ответ и прочих случаев, когда пост не является попыткой ответа. Если автор поста пытался ответить на вопрос, но ответил неправильно - стоит просто оставить комментарий. И минусануть по желанию.

Answer (score -1):

Youtube намеренно прячет ссылки на источник видео, потому что скачивание запрещено их политикой, но вы можете получить ссылку при помощи расширения [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net).

Для примера, возьмём видео отсюда: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4

При помощи расширения можно узнать детальную информацию о видео и там же скопировать полную ссылку (videoUrl):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<video src="https://r3---sn-x0gvuxa-3c2l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1582352598&ei=dnRQXpD-BsHi7QTc-5HwCg&ip=91.223.126.227&id=o-AOCDZhQ_V7RfOG4YYePmL_xMH3LvEo0kTjfYuwnW8bq0&itag=247&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-x0gvuxa-3c2l%2Csn-3c27sn7d&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pcm2cms=yes&pl=24&nh=%2CIgpwcjAxLmticDAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&initcwndbps=695000&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=62816230&dur=596.457&lmt=1536987790334338&mt=1582330896&fvip=15&keepalive=yes&fexp=23842630&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAM0zFykSWpdqm4e7Etqf9Xty3MFDutOw2BCf6SiWQYGHAiEArMoYUaitcKXDR9zkw41QAei3csWh-J0fw1ZdR-ONfSo%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cnh%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRQIhAIdePaCRupnJMLUHUwNwnVoUKzru5lNiNNlRw0cBpe36AiBcEl3Yuqzy25teiK2i4Ui2KrCxJMtO2IvbOcjgSYAZzw%3D%3D&alr=yes&cpn=uPoChylsbtJHiPMe&cver=2.20200221.03.00&rn=17&rbuf=0" controls width="320" height="240" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YE7VzlLtp-4/default.jpg">
```

**Важное примечание**

Увы, этот метод работал раньше, но сейчас пример кода выше будет работать только у меня, и то не долго. Они добавили в урл привязку к айпи и времени. Так что, если вкратце, то никаким простым способом вам этого не сделать. Заливайте видео на свой сайт. Ничего кроме продажи рекламы гуглов не волнует.